# Using sed /unix command to replace date (yyyymmdd)in between

Tags: sed

Let's say I have three .dat  files as below

```
Psdm_123_20200221.dat
Psdm_20200221.dat
Psdm_acc_20200221_12345667.dat
```

Output

```
Psdm_123*.dat
Psdm_*.dat
Psdm_acc_*.dat
```

Comment: Do we need to remove the date in the filename? or replace it with asterisks?

Comment: Removing the date will also work

Comment: which distro of linux are you using?

Comment: do we just need to print? or rename the file?

Comment: Which version of `sed` are you using? In many cases it may be possible to use more or less elegant syntax depending on the version. Also, please specify explicitly if you want to replace only the date specification or everything starting from the date until (but excluding) the filename extension with an `*`.

Answer (score 1):

The following `sed` command should do the task:

```
sed 's/20[0-9]\{2\}\(0[1-9]\|1[012]\)\([012][0-9]\|3[01]\)[^.]*/*/'
```

If your `sed` understands the `-r` or `-E` option, you can dispense with most of the backslashes:

```
sed -r 's/20[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[012])([012][0-9]|3[01])[^.]*/*/'
```

This will look for a pattern "YYYYMMDD" with some plausibility checks (only years between 2000 and 2099, months in the range from 01 - 12, days in the range from 01 - 31) and replace that *and anything afterwards, up to but excluding the filename extension, provided there is only one literal `.` in the filename after the date*. This is performed by accepting "everything but a `.` zero or more times" (`[^.]*`) in the expression to be replaces.